# Injecting JSON data into an AngularJS Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I searched all over S-O for an answer to this issue, but none seemed to work for my particular case. If this is potentially a duplicate, please forgive me.

What I'm trying to do is insert my JSON data into a modal (which uses UI-Bootstrap) but I've been running in to trouble. I tried many different examples found through googling, but nothing showed the data.

I created a new View for the modal window and the code looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">More Info</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{user.username}}</p>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ user.username }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ user.username }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

This modal is called on the main.html (main view) which looks like this:

```
<md-scroll-shrink><header sticky layout="row" layout-xs="column" class="header">
  <h3 class="text-center affix-top ">User Directory</h3>
</header>
</md-scroll-shrink>


<div layout="row" layout-md="column">


    <div flex>
      <md-card id="card" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">{{user.name}}</span>
            <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
            <span class="md-subhead">{{user.email}}</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
          <md-card-title-media>

          </md-card-title-media>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <button  ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-success">More Info</button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>
    </div>







</div>
```

And finally here is the main controller(main.js):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name peapodTestApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the peapodTestApp
 */

angular.module('peapodTestApp')
  .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',function($scope,$uibModalInstance,UserService){
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
  })

  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,UserService,$uibModal,$log) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma',
      'ngMaterial'
    ];

    $scope.users = UserService;
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (UserService,size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        user: function () {
          return $scope.user;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };



  })
  .service('UserService',function(){
    var user = [{

    "id": 1,

    "name": "Leanne Graham",

    "username": "Bret",

    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",

    "address": {

        "street": "Kulas Light",

        "suite": "Apt. 556",

        "city": "Gwenborough",

        "zipcode": "92998­3874",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­37.3159",

            "lng": "81.1496"

        }

    },

    "phone": false,

    "website": "hildegard.org",

    "company": {

        "name": "Romaguera­Crona",

        "catchPhrase": "Multi­layered client­server neural­net",

        "bs": "harness real­time e­markets",



    }

},

{

    "id": 2,

    "name": "Ervin Howell",

    "username": "Antonette",

    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",

    "address": {

        "street": "Victor Plains",

        "suite": "Suite 879",

        "city": "Wisokyburgh",

        "zipcode": "90566­7771",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­43.9509",

            "lng": "­34.4618"

        }

    },

    "phone": "010­692­6593 x09125",

    "website": "anastasia.net",

    "company": {

        "name": "Deckow­Crist",

        "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",

        "bs": "synergize scalable supply­chains"

    }

},

{

    "id": 3,

    "name": "Clementine Bauch",

    "username": "Samantha",

    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",

    "address": {

        "street": "Douglas Extension",

        "suite": "Suite 847",

        "city": "McKenziehaven",

        "zipcode": "59590­4157",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­68.6102",

            "lng": "­47.0653"

        }

    },

    "phone": "",

    "website": "ramiro.info",

    "company": {

        "name": "Romaguera­Jacobson",

        "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",

        "bs": "e­enable strategic applications"

    }

},

{

    "id": 4,

    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",

    "username": "Karianne",

    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",

    "address": {

        "street": "Hoeger Mall",

        "suite": "Apt. 692",

        "city": "South Elvis",

        "zipcode": "53919­4257",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "29.4572",

            "lng": "­164.2990"

        }

    },

    "phone": "493­170­9623 x156",

    "website": "kale.biz",

    "company": {

        "name": "Robel­Corkery",

        "catchPhrase": "Multi­tiered zero tolerance productivity",

        "bs": "transition cutting­edge web services"

    }

},

{

    "id": 5,

    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",

    "username": "Kamren",

    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",

    "address": {

        "street": "Skiles Walks",

        "suite": "Suite 351",

        "city": "Roscoeview",

        "zipcode": "33263",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­31.8129",

            "lng": "62.5342"

        }

    },

    "phone": "(254)954­1289",

    "website": "demarco.info",

    "company": {

        "name": "Keebler LLC",

        "catchPhrase": "User­centric fault­tolerant solution",

        "bs": "revolutionize end­to­end systems"

    }

},

{

    "id": 6,

    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",

    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",

    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",

    "address": {

        "street": "Norberto Crossing",

        "suite": "Apt. 950",

        "city": "South Christy",

        "zipcode": "23505­1337",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­71.4197",

            "lng": "71.7478"

        }

    },

    "phone": "",

    "website": "ola.org",

    "company": {

        "name": "Considine­Lockman",

        "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom­line interface",

        "bs": "e­enable innovative applications"

    }

},

{

    "id": 7,

    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",

    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",

    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",

    "address": {

        "street": "Rex Trail",

        "suite": "Suite 280",

        "city": "Howemouth",

        "zipcode": "58804­1099",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "24.8918",

            "lng": "21.8984"

        }

    },

    "phone": "210.067.6132",

    "website": "elvis.io",

    "company": {

        "name": "Johns Group",

        "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task­force",

        "bs": "generate enterprise e­tailers"

    }

},

{

    "id": 8,

    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",

    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",

    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",

    "address": {

        "street": "Ellsworth Summit",

        "suite": "Suite 729",

        "city": "Aliyaview",

        "zipcode": "45169",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "­14.3990",

            "lng": "­120.7677"

        }

    },

    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",

    "website": "jacynthe.com",

    "company": {

        "name": "Abernathy Group",

        "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",

        "bs": "e­enable extensible e­tailers"

    }

},

{

    "id": 9,

    "name": "Glenna Reichert",

    "username": "Delphine",

    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",

    "address": {

        "street": "Dayna Park",

        "suite": "Suite 449",

        "city": "Bartholomebury",

        "zipcode": "76495­3109",

        "geo": {

            "lat": "24.6463",

            "lng": "­168.8889"

        }

    },

    "phone": "(775)976­6794 x41206",

    "website": "conrad.com",

    "company": {

        "name": "Yost and Sons",

        "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually­based project",

        "bs": "aggregate real­time technologies"

    }

}

];

    return user;
  })
```

Also, BTW I tried updating an earlier question but never received a response. If anyone has any tips, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

**UPDATE** Unfortunately I am still having trouble getting my modal to display my JSON values, I've tried the suggested fixes and still nothing...any other suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the modalInstanceCtrl need to receive the resolve variable

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',function($scope,$uibModalInstance,user){
    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
```

inject the resolved user instead of the userService

Comment: according to your modal view you will also need users base on `ng-repeat="user in users"` just pass the users via resolve and receive it in the controllers too

Comment: Would you be willing to display what you mean in a plunker? I'm fairly new to Angular so I'm not sure how to pass the users via resolve etc.

Comment: would love too, but i have some task now. perhaps setup your code in plunker so i can edit it easily ?

Comment: Sure here's the plunker code http://plnkr.co/edit/YvDX2a7CVSkGp3BWBoVu?p=streamer  I appreciate the help and your time

Comment: @JoelCarter you fiddle doesnt work. please setup with working modal, injected dependencies, etc

Comment: here is a working angular + bootstrap modal example
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2dgeE7s3Gtghxyy8zSOE?p=preview) passing data via resolve

Comment: I seem to be having trouble with the plunker...but I do have an update git repo if that helps

Comment: Hey @kiro112 I see the plunker suggestion but it's not exactly what I'm looking for...I tried the suggestion and kept getting errors. I'm thinking that my function can't see the JSON data, but I'm still a bit stumped on how to get it to be seen by the modal function...